# Syntax for compressing a partition table

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the syntax to compress a partitioned table in Microsoft SQL server ?

Comment: Oh this site you are expected to have carried out your own research in advance of asking a question, and you need to include in your question the research you have done, the ideas you have had, and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

To compress one or more partitions on a row-store table/index use [ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#data_compression).

To switch to columnstore compression create a new clustered columnstore index.